# Presto SQL left joining using ST_intersects, ST_crosses yield unexpected results

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

Sorry if title is not informative.

Using AWS Athena.

Have two tables:

1.transaction_table

```
location      time         status    type    ....   deleted_at
  BLOB     2020-09-01
  BLOB     2020-09-02
  BLOB     2020-09-03
```

2.area_table

```
 boundary              created_at     deleted_at
  POLYGON((...))       2020-09-01       null
  POLYGON((...))       2020-09-01       null
  POLYGON((...))       2020-09-01     2020-10-01
```

For Each row in transaction_table I want add appropriate boundary

```
    select date(time) as dt
         , count(time) As cnt
      from transaction_table t
 left join area_table a
        on ST_intersects(boundary, ST_Point(ST_X(t.location), ST_Y(t.location)))
     where t.status = 'complete'
       and t.deleted_at is null
       and t.time >= date('2020-09-01')
       and a.deleted_at is null
  group by date(withdraw_time);
```

Problem is when I use ST_intersects or ST_contains daily cnt decreases from query without left join which does not make sense to me since left join will always output equal or greater rows that left table.

Both left, right table have none null values and there are no multiple joins that increases number of rows (if so, query with left join more rows than without)

Right now using ST_Crosses fixes the problem -> outputs same result with/without left join. But I am not sure why number of rows decrease in my query above.

**EDIT:** ST_Crosses doesn't seem to join any rows hence same value as querying without left join. So my question is why does daily cnt decrease when using left join ST_intersects or ST_contains? Same query in Mysql(ST_point -> point) runs perfectly fine.

From https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-point.html.

- Point(lat,lng) give point object which is zero-dimension
- ST_Point(lat,lng) is a geometry and is 2-d.

So I guess using ST_intersects(Geom,Geom) and ST_intersects(Geom, Point) works diffrently, but this still do not explain reduced daily cnt on left join.

Answer (score 1):

Athena is based on Presto 0.172 - according to their release notes there were no geospatial functions available:

- [Presto Functions in Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html)
- [Presto 01.72 Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/index.html)

Athena's geospatial functions are implemented as a Presto Plugin and the full Reference is available here: [List of Supported Geospatial Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-functions-list.html).

One thing to consider is actually the order of arguments of `ST_POINT` being `ST_POINT(longitude, latitude)`, so longitude being the first argument and latitude the second.

You are also referring left and right table in the where condition, this definitely could result in having less rows.